# Combining Powershell script to call function and get the AD attributes value

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I need to use a PowerShell function to format the phone number like below:

```
Function Format-TelephoneNumber
{
    Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias('Number')]
        [string]$TelephoneNumber,
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [string]$DefaultCountryCode = '+44'
    )
    Process
    {
        $formattedNumber = $TelephoneNumber -replace '[\x09 ]'
        If ($formattedNumber -match '\A(?<CountryCode>\+[1-9]\d|0)(?<Number>\d*)\Z')
        {
            If ($Matches['CountryCode'] -eq '0')
            {
                $countryCode = $defaultCountryCode
            }
            Else
            {
                $countryCode = $Matches['CountryCode']
            }
            $formattedNumber = $countryCode + ' '
            $formattedNumber += -join $Matches['Number'][0 .. 2] + ' '
            $formattedNumber += -join $Matches['Number'][3 .. 5] + ' '
            $formattedNumber += -join $Matches['Number'][6 .. 8]
            $formattedNumber
        }
        Else
        {
            Write-Error "Unable to parse the string '$($number)' as telephone number!"
        }
    }
}
```

The below script is for retrieving the value of Phone Number from AD Attribute:

```
$sysInfo = New-Object -ComObject 'ADSystemInfo'
$userDN = $sysInfo.GetType().InvokeMember('UserName', 'GetProperty', $null, $sysInfo, $null)
$adUser = [ADSI]"LDAP://$($userDN)"
[void][Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($sysInfo)

Write-Host $adUser.mobile.ToString() -ForegroundColor Green
```

How can I call the script?

I have tried below but failed:

```
Write-Host "This is raw from AD: $($adUser.mobile.ToString())" -ForegroundColor Yellow

$Formatted = Format-TelephoneNumber -TelephoneNumber $adUser.mobile.ToString()
Write-Host "This is processed using Function: " "$($Formatted)" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I don't see any issue in how you call the function

Comment: Is it intentional that your function removes the last digit of the telephone number? I'd update the ranges to `0 .. 3`/`4 .. 6`/`7 .. 9` as this doesn't break up the area code and includes the last digit.

Comment: @JamesC.no, it is not intentional, so how to update that on the script?

Comment: @guiwhatsthat, somehow the result is not displaying properly?
I need the proper way to call the function and assign the result into Variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd use a different Format-TelephoneNumber function because as [James C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2208505/james-c) commented, your function may truncate last digit(s) from the number.
Below is my attempt:

```
function Format-TelephoneNumber {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias('Number')]
        [string]$TelephoneNumber,

        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [string]$DefaultCountryCode = '+44'
    )
    Process {
        # replace all hyphens and other possible joining characters with space and trim the result
        $number = ($TelephoneNumber -replace '[._~-]', ' ').Trim()
        # test if the number starts with a country code
        if ($number -match '^(\+\d+)\s') {
            $countryCode = $Matches[1]
            $number = $number.Substring($countryCode.Length).Trim()
        }
        else {
            $countryCode = $DefaultCountryCode
        }

        # remove leading zero and any non-digits
        $number = $number -replace '^0|\D', ''

        if ($number.Length -lt 9) {
            Write-Warning "Unable to parse the string '$($TelephoneNumber)' as telephone number!"
        }
        else {
            $parts = @($countryCode)
            # split the remaining string in to 3-character parts (+ possible remainder)
            $parts += $number -split '(\d{3})' | Where-Object { $_ }
            return $parts -join ' '
        }
    }
}
```

Why not use the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet to find the `mobile` property? Something like:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# return the mobile phone number for a user as string or nothing if not found
# $userID is either the users distinguished name, the GUID, the user SID, or the SamAccountName.
$mobile = Get-ADUser -Identity $userID -Properties MobilePhone | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MobilePhone
```

<sup>Note: `MobilePhone` is the PowerShell or GUI name for the `mobile` attribute, but you may use either.</sup>

Then, if you have this mobile number as string format it using the `Format-TelephoneNumber` function:

```
if ($mobile) { 
    Write-Host "This is raw from AD: $mobile" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $formatted = Format-TelephoneNumber -TelephoneNumber $mobile
    Write-Host "This is formatted: $formatted" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Hope that answers your question